# laravel internal Error, What is the problem?

Tags: ajax, laravel

When I try to submit the form using ajax I'm getting **500 (Internal Server Error)** error.

Can any one tell me what is the wrong m I doing?
Here is my ajax, route, controller code.

**Ajax**

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
         }
       });


 $("#subscribe_form").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       console.log('a');
       $.ajax({
        url: "subscribe/store",
        type: 'post',
        //dataType: JSON,
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,


        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function () {
            console.log('success');

        }
    });
});
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('subscribe/store', 'SubscribeController@store')
->name('subscribe.store');
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Subscriber::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('index');
}
```

**Form**

```
            <form id="subscribe_form" style="margin-bottom: 5px" >
                @csrf
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" id="subemail">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark sub" id="subscribe">Subscribe</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Please, add a screenshot of the error you are getting.

Comment: It's better to add the error message here.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/otitdu

Comment: Can you click on that link it'll show you error what exactly error are you getting?

Comment: I saw that. It's not enough. Click on the `network` tab and see the error message.

Comment: Do u mean it? https://prnt.sc/otiwmz

Comment: Yes click on that you'll see your error.

Comment: Yes, click on `store` to see the actual error

Comment: It's probably something messed up in your .env file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change your ajax and form code like this.

**Ajax Code**

```
$('body').on('submit','#subscribe_form',function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       console.log('a');
       $.ajax({
        url : $(this).attr('action'),
        data: new FormData(this),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,       
        cache: false,             
        processData:false, 
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function () {
            console.log('success');

        }
    });
});
```

**Form code**

```
<form id="subscribe_form" style="margin-bottom: 5px" action="{{ route('subscribe.store') }}">
                @csrf
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" id="subemail">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark sub" id="subscribe">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

If you still get 500 error then you may go as screen shot you'll get what errors exactly are.

[image]

Comment: have you click on 500 store method and can you tell me what is the error?

Comment: No, Click on Response which is next to preview. you'll see actual error over there.

Comment: Check `preview`

Comment: Oh, i found the problem. I wrote incorrect controller name. Thank you very much.

Comment: Okay, Next time be careful if you use ajax your error will display in network.

Comment: Okay, Thank you.